# Using single data store for single grid instance which is used everywhere in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

**SCENARIO**

> I am having a gridpanel(say **grid**),which is been used everywhere in my application.Suppose components (**panel1** and **panel2**) are using **grid**.This **grid** is using a store(**store1**).I want to **update grid in panel1 without updating grid in panel2**.

**MY PROBLEM**

> I **dont want to use different stores** for grid in panel1 and panel2.
>   Is their any way this could be achieved.
>
> I tried binding store(with new data) to grid in panel1.But grids in both panel1 and panel2 are getting updated.

If I was not clear enough,Please let me know.Please help me resolve this.Thnks a lot.

```
**For reference**
/*my grid*/
Ext.define('APP.view.mygrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mygrid',
store:'store1',
columns: [ ...  ]


/*my panels*/
{
  xtype:'panel',
  items:[
         {
           xtype :'mygrid',
         }
       ],
  xtype:'panel',
  items:[
         {
           xtype :'mygrid',
         }
        ],
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the store for your second panel, so try this:

```
var secondStore=Ext.create('your_store');
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        title: 'grid1',
        store: 'your_store'
    },{
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        title: 'grid2',
        store: secondStore
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks.Please look into my edit(For reference).I want to update the grid in 1st panel with different data,but grid in second panel also gets updated.

Comment: try to create two grids, grid1 with store1 and grid 2 with store2. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you update your grid by some local changes in the store, and you do not make a call to your web service. Then you can try doing this:

```
store.suspendEvents(false); // false: do not queue events
// do some data changes now
store.resumeEvents();

grid.getView().refresh(); // only on the first grid
```

Comment: Thanks @Christoph.I have resolved this by creating a store each time during component(grid) initialization.

Answer (score 0):

> I have resolved this by creating a instace of the store each time when
>   the grid is called.Please have a look :

```
initComponent   : function() {
    this.items = [          
        {
            xtype   : 'myPanelgrids'
            name    : 'panel1' // this is the extra config to identify the grid in added in my panel1
        }

    ];
    this.callParent();
},
listeners: {
    render: function(){
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', 
            {
                model: 'App.model.MyModel',
                autoLoad: true,
                 proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url:'app/data/configdata.json',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root : 'myroot'//maintained a json property file with different roots for grids in panel1 and panel2
                        }
                    }
            }
        );

        this.down('grid').reconfigure(store);
    }
}
```

> I am updating the store of particular grid from my controller.